# Float CSS Badge next to each other I guess I want to float

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I would like to know how to float all my badges next to each other in the footer menu. I have four badges so far but could be up to six. The badges are my SSL, AVG, BBB, Etc... I am very very new to all this website building stuff. I use Joomla 3.1 and use a paid up to date template. I can see all the codes and add the badges but they always pop up on top of each other. I had one person help me but they did it in tables and told me that it would work but that it was not the right way to do it. Please remember when helping me that I am a child learning to color for the first time when it comes to this :) Thanks for any help that any one my be able to give.

If you look at the bottom of this page( http://www.jcluforever.com/J-ADORE-GOD-CHRISTIAN-T-SHIRT-p/ts-jdrgod-prp.htm )that the badges they have for payment, SSl, and up front; this is how I want my to line up only I would like mine in the footer and I have like 5 that I would be adding
some idea of what I would have is 
    https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;">

**next one would be**

```
<div id="avgthreatlabs_safetybadge_small"><noscript><a href="http://www.avgthreatlabs.com?utm_source=H&utm_medium=NA&utm_campaign=SSBW" target="_blank">AVG Threatlabs</a></noscript></div><script language="javascript" src="https://api.avgthreatlabs.com/static/js/security_s.js"></script>
```

**next would be**

```
<!--- DO NOT EDIT - GlobalSign SSL Site Seal Code - DO NOT EDIT ---><table width=130 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 title="CLICK TO VERIFY: This site uses a GlobalSign SSL Certificate to secure your personal information." ><tr><td><span id="ss_img_wrapper_110-55_flash_en"><a href="http://www.globalsign.com/" target=_blank title="SSL"><img alt="SSL" border=0 id="ss_img" src="//seal.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/images/gs_noscript_110-55_en.gif"></a></span><script type="text/javascript" src="//seal.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/gs_flash_110-55_en.js" ></script><br /><a href="http://www.globalsign.com/" target=_blank  style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font:bold 8px arial; margin:0px; padding:0px;">GlobalSign SSL Certificates</a></td></tr></table><!--- DO NOT EDIT - GlobalSign SSL Site Seal Code - DO NOT EDIT --->
```

and so on and so on until I place all the badge I want or can or need to. I am not sure what part of the template you need it is all short or what is called LESS I am told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to have these badges nested in an unordered list. Each badge would be inside of a list item. For this example, let's say each badge is just an image. Try this:

```
<ul class="my-list">
<li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="2.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="3.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Then, in your stylesheet, write:

```
.mylist {
   list-style:none;
} 

.mylist li {
    float:left;
}
```

This will float all your items to the left of the page and "stack" the list items beside each-other, instead of on top of each-other.

Comment: Thanks Invot for the answer. I am still lost as I know nothing about codes I do not even know how to get the template to show me the code. I can get to the code sheet but they are all LESS code or just lots of lines like this ---------------------

Comment: I'm no fan of LESS. It takes a lot of getting used to. As a newbie I would recommend not messing with it. 

What you can do to insert style codes without messing with LESS is inserting it directly into the HTML using the 'style' tag. For example: `<ul style="list-style:none;">` and `<li style="float:left;">`

Comment: Thanks again. I have no idea how to do it and not even with firebug and the template came with LESS. In any case thanks for the info I might see what I can do with but most likely just pay someone to add the code real fast to my site and be done with it...Again thanks now off to Fiverr.com to see if I can find someone to post the codes hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Learning web design is a process that will require patients, dedication, and more trial and error than you can imagine. It isn't completely dissimilar from learning a new spoken language, except that instead of learning one, you learn several, and then learn how to make them work together to create what you want. If this doesn't interest you, and you just want to run your website or online business, then I would consider hiring a web designer or firm to maintain the code that powers your business; however, if learning is truly what you want to do, then read!

### HTML

HTML, or Hypertext Markup Language, is the code you write to deliver data to the browser. It is not extremely complicated to gain a basic understanding of how HTML works. I'm not going to try and explain the entire thing here, but [here is a great beginner tutorial](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/).

### CSS

CSS, or Cascading Style Sheets, is a different language that you use, in order to tell the browser how your data should appear. It is very light weight, and pretty much just plain English. [Here is an easy to follow guide to CSS](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/).

If you read through these two guides, and do a little experimenting on your own, I believe that you will be able to solve the problem on your own. Once you have the basics of HTML and CSS down, there is still a ton to learn, but once you master the basics, you will be in a much better position to pick up more.

Happy coding, and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do want to learn but right now I have a site up and running and all I need to do is add the badges and than I can play around on other sites to learn as this one starts to make money. Almost everything I am using is free do to the fact that I have no means of money at this time. I start college Sept 9th and was lucky to get a grant for that. I am sure I could had the code my safe but I dont know how to make it where it is not the LESS code. My site is holychristianwear.com Thanks for all the help that any one can and has given.